# iPad / iPhone Chrome not show text in a input button

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome, ipad

I have a page which has an input button.

In Chrome the button text is not displayed

[image]

In Safari and Firefox it looks correctly.

[image]

I have the latest Chrome update

any idea why this happens?

```css
.button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #003245;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 175px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 3em auto 0;
  border: 1px solid #003245;
  display: block;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  position: relative;
  pointer: default;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" class="button">
```

Comment: Remove spaces from the colors. I am voting to close as typo. Also there is no CSS rule called pointer. It is cursor and the value can be pointer

Comment: The original code was correctly, with no spaces. I have replaced the rule "pointer",  but the text is not displayed

Comment: I fixed your code. I removed the space from `# 003245` twice. It runs now on mobile - you can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wyo5m3cf/

Answer (score -1):

Colour Hex code has space in it  `border: 1px solid # 003245;` and `color: # 003245;` remove the space

```css
.button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #003245;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 175px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 3em auto 0;
  border: 1px solid #003245;
  display: block;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  position: relative;
  pointer: default;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" class="button">
```

Comment: I have replaced thespaces,  but the text is not displayed

Comment: Maybe some property gets overridden. Try removing the "button" class and test if it works and after that add the "button" class property and remove CSS property one by one. I hope this will help you debug this.